# How to escape backslash and question mark characters using rlike in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I have a hive query to filter out '/s?' from the data but it doesn't seem to work and I am getting very broad matches

```
where colA rlike '/s?'    
where colA rlike '\/s\?'
```

both cases return same results even if I escape the characters

Comment: ``/`` does not need escaping and `?` can be either escaped as ``\\`` or just put it into a char class - `[?]`

Comment: thanks..that worked!

Comment: @user7088181 you should accept the answer then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` does not need escaping and `?` can be either escaped as `\\` or just put it into a char class - `[?]`.

Use

```
where colA rlike '/s[?]'
```